# Что есть Backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Из прочитанного понял, что это просто навороченный шаблонизатор, чем он лучше, например, jquery? Разделение логики и шаблона я могу сделать и в чистом js, и в том же jqery.

Answer (score 9):

Прочитайте еще раз.
[backbone.js](/questions/tagged/backbone.js) - не шаблонизатор, в том смысле в каком шаблонизатор понимают в мире фронтэнда (как всякие jade, handlebars etc).

Пожалуйста, используйте чистый js или jquery если вам так удобно.
Никто не запретит писать велосипеды человеку, который любит и хочет писать велосипеды.
Но вот когда вам надо будет написать полноценное spa приложение а не просто слайдер, то это будет достаточно долго.
А когда Вы начнете писать второе spa-приложение, то заметите что очень много кода Вы уже писали в прошлом, и хорошо бы не писать его еще раз.

Так вот, есть в мире разработчики, которые написали этих spa приложений разной сложности больше десятка. И иногда они пишут библиотеки, собирая в них то, что скорее всего пригодится в следующем приложении. Backbone - одна из таких библиотек.

Конкретно [backbone.js](/questions/tagged/backbone.js), это такая некоторая небольшая заготовка, каркас для реализации сложного приложения на основе MV* паттерна.  Включает в себя роутер, кастомные события, реализацию моделей и коллекций etc.

Можно написать этот каркас самому, по пути собрав многие сотни граблей. Очень смелый путь. Много нового узнаете. (Хорошее приложение в срок не напишете скорее всего, но это дело десятое, правда?)