# Зачем нужны js фреймворки?

Tags: javascript, jquery, framework

Вопрос простой.
Зачем использовать фреймворки JS когда можно писать на том же jQuery?

Comment: чтобы даже с использованием jQuery писать еще меньше велосипедов

Comment: когда-то я был поклонником Dojo и то же самое думал про jQuery ;-))

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что есть Backbone?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559861/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-backbone)

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы.
Но мне стоило по-лучше Гуглить.
Нашёл статью которая отвечает как раз на мой вопрос:
https://weburoki.pro/zachem-nuzhny-js-frejmvorki

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Неправильно говорить: "писать на **jQuery**", так как **jQuery** — это библиотека, а не язык. Пишут на **JavaScript**, а **jQuery** используют.

Никто не запрещает использовать чистый **JavaScript** (без дополнительных фрейворков и библиотек), но тогда придется писать много кода каждый раз и это будет отнимать много времени.

Основное назначение **jQuery** — прямая работа с **HTML**. Но при разработке сложных приложений этого может быть не достаточно, так как помимо прямой работы с **HTML** есть множество других задач: сохранение и отображение данных, взаимодействие с пользователем, веб-сокеты и т.п. Для решения этих задач и созданы различные фреймворки.

Для небольших проектов даже **jQuery** может быть слишком много и лучше написать на чистом **JavaScript**.

**Дополнение**:

Как верно заметил [pepel_xD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194692/pepel-xd), **jQuery** так же выполняет функцию унификации браузеров. То есть избавляете от необходимости проверять в каком браузер работает код и учитывать особенности этого браузера. **jQuery** делает это за вас в автоматически.

Comment: Только я бы еще добавил, что JQ в основном используют для кроссбраузерности, что - бы не писать кучу полифилов.... Но в нынешних реалия все  браузеры более менее стабильно одинаково поддерживают стандарт. В следствии чего не нужна эта библиотека...

Comment: @pepel_xD согласен. Добавлю в ответ.